# mysql update with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is simple but I'm have a mental block.

I need to update all products that belongs to a category. The product is assigned to a category in an association table.

so it's something like

```
UPDATE product P1 
SET myflag = 1 
WHERE P1.productid IN (
    SELECT CA.productid 
    FROM category_associations CA 
    WHERE CA.categoryid = '500'
)
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

A `JOIN` will typically have the optimal execution plan, but `IN` can be inefficient:

```
UPDATE 
   product P1 JOIN
   category_associations ca 
      ON ca.productId = P1.productId 
      AND ca.categoryId = '500'
SET P1.myflag = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted, the join syntax on update alluded me.

Answer (score 0):

another way to write it is:

```
UPDATE product
SET myflag = 1
FROM product P1 JOIN
   category_associations ca 
      ON ca.productId = P1.productId 
WHERE ca.categoryId = '500'
```